# Как посчитать количество комбинаций пароля?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Допустим есть 8 символов. 3 Символа большие заглавные, 5 строчные. Сколько комбинаций паролей можно нагенерировать под эти символы?

Интересует больше математический расчет) Допустим если у нас пароль из трех цифр и возможны только два значения, то можно получить 8 комбинаций. 2^3=8/

```
000
001
100
...
```

Это простой пример конечно.

Comment: не очень в тему программерского сайта конечно.

Comment: (26^8)*C(8,3). Для английского алфавита из 26 букв. Элементарная комбинаторика. С(8,3) - к-во перестановок.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, тут также принято задавать вопросы по математике

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
26^8 * C(8,3) == 26^8 * (8! / (3! * (8-3)!))
```

26^8 - количество вариантов без учета регистра, С(8,3) - количество способов расставить 3 заглавные буквы в 8 позиций.

Для простой ситуации 2 символа а и б и 2 позиции (1 символ заглавный):
аА, Аа, аБ, Аб, бА, Ба, бБ, Бб - 8 вариантов.
Проверяем (2^2) * (2! / (1! * 1!)) = 4 * 2 = 8/

Comment: @KromStern, так лучше? Повторюсь, это элементарная комбинаторика.

Comment: Согласен. Так и получается. Но это если мы не используем варианты когда не все 8 позиций символов заполнены. В противном случае, 26 нужно менять на 27.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, Вы безусловно правы - это для пароля длиной РОВНО 8 букв. Про 27 не поясните?

Comment: @andy.37 мне кажется вы и сами догадываетесь. Если мы допускаем пароль, к примеру АаА, ко всем буквам в выборе (их 26) добавляем нулевой символ. Получается 26+1 = 27.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, разве тогда не получится, что `_AaA` и `АаА_` - различны? (_ - типа пустой символ). ИМХО, если мы добавим один (или больше) символов без возможности смены регистра - задача перестает быть тривиальной.

Comment: @KromStern верхний и нижний регистр мы задаем подстановкой сочетаний - C(8,3). Пробел на это не влияет. Этот символ безотносителен регистра.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin у Вас получается, что положение пробела в строке изменяет пароль, что не так. Имхо будет P(8) + P(7) + ... P(минимальное к-во символов). Все просто)

Comment: @andy.37 _AaA и АаА_ и должны получиться различными. Конечно ваш пароль может быть и тот и другой. Ещё раз повторюсь, пустой символ есть и в верхнем и нижнем регистре.

Comment: В вопросе про пробел не сказано. Но если бы он не обрезался, то `_ааа` и `ааа_` были бы действительно разными паролями.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin согласен. спасибо за объяснение. "пустой символ есть и в верхнем и нижнем регистре" - в такой постановке звучит сомнительно.

Comment: Коллеги, я чего-то видимо туманно объясняю. Если у нас 8 символов, то пароль ааа = aaa_ _ _ _ _ _; Но также есть перестановка _aaa_ _ _ _ _ и т.д. и это всё разные варианты.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, вопрос формулировок. У вас "пустой символ" - не то же что наше "отсутствие символа" (т.е. пароль из 7 букв, а не из восьми). Т.е., по Вашему, добавить в алфавит один символ без возможности смены регистра или добавить символ с такой возможностью не изменит к-во комбинаций?

Comment: @andy.37 похоже ошибаюсь.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, исходя из заданной в ответе формулы, что оставляя прежнее количество символов (8), но увеличивая алфавит (3->4) и, как следствие, ожидая большее количество вариантов сочетаний алфавитных значений, мы получаем парадоксальное уменьшение сложности? А если символов будет 8, а заглавных букв тоже 8, то всё сломается, нафиг?)
И что делать, если символов 8, а заглавных букв 10? У меня какие-то отрицательные числа получаются) Ну, а если не глумиться, то вы неправильно выбрали формулу и это сильно бросается в глаза

Comment: Если есть 8 символов (3 больших, длинных символа, и 5 коротких, маленьких), то можно бесконечное количество комбинаций нагенерировать. Даже если у меня будет один большой длинный символ - всё равно бесконечно.
И такой ответ будет пока не определится длина пароля. Если длина равна n, то вариантов 8^n или 2^3n. Так для n=3, паролей будет 8^3=8*8*8=512 (или 2^9). Степень двойки все помнят до 32, и понятно, что при n=10, количество будет равно, примерно, (4млр/2)/2=1073741824